# Can I replicate a database to different regions for read AND write access & synchronize?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

We plan to have users all over the world who will access our web application. But our database is located in US-West. We want the same database in Mumbai. We did create a read-replica, but it's pointless if we need to execute write scripts there right?

How do companies solve this scenario? How do companies allow two databases to exist across regions where they both synchronize their data for reading and write access? I basically want a master-master relationship. Not a master-slave.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your DBA experience? Implementing global Master-Master Read-Write databases requires time, money (a lot) and lots of experience. Not counting full time DBAs to continuously monitor and manage these setups. Just the latency issues for synchronous replication going half way around the world will be a BIG issue. Unless you employ experts in your company for databases and HA and DR, stay with read replicas and let a managed service such as RDS do the heavy work. You will have big delays in both Master-Master and updating a Master-Read-Replica going across the world.

Comment: Read-only read-replicas are not "pointless". Depending on your application, reads from your database may outweigh writes by a large margin. If you use local read-replicas, then those reads will be much faster, despite needing to write to another region.